# Round 1,7346 to 1,74

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I use `Math.Round(1.7346, 2, AwayFromZero)` which should give me 1,74 - but it actually gives me 1.73.

I know it is because of this:

> "Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing
>   decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic
>   operations on floating-point values, in some cases the Round(Double,
>   Int32, MidpointRounding) method may not appear to round midpoint
>   values as specified by the mode parameter. This is illustrated in the
>   following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13 instead of 2.14.
>   This occurs because internally the method multiplies value by 10 *
>   digits, and the multiplication operation in this case suffers from a
>   loss of precision."

But which .NET Method should I actually use to do correct rounding?

Comment: `MidpointRounding` only takes effect when the stuff following the digits you want is like "50000".  For other cases, `Round` lives up to its name -- it *rounds* to the closest number with that many decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

1.7346 should be rounded to 1.73, even with [`AwayFromZero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx), since that only changes the rounding behavior "when a number is halfway between two others" (e.g. if it had been 1.735).

The behavior you want can be obtained with

```
Math.Round(Math.Round(1.7346, 3, AwayFromZero), 2, AwayFromZero)
```

(but don't consider this anything more than a hack).

Comment: thank you - this is what i tried now and works.

even i am bit confused, since 

1,7346 should be roundet to 1,735 should be rounded to 1,74

thats what we expect at least here in europe?

Comment: @user1083275 nope. When rounding to two decimal digits we (Europeans) only take the first three decimal digits into account and omit the rest. In your case we only take a look at `1.734` and decide that because of the `4` that the rounded value be `1.73`. In rounding you don't take multiple iterations. When you round to `n` decimal digits, you base your decision solely on the value of the `(n+1)` decimal digit

Comment: Not in the UK at least; 1.7346 to 2dp is 1.73, because the 0.004 rounds down, not up - you don't keep rounding from the least significant digit until you've reached your precision level

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is partly wrong. 1.7346 is rounded to 1.73 because of the semantics of `AwayFromZero`, i.e.:

- < 0.5 → 0.0
- 0.5 → 1.0
- > 0.5 → 1.0
- < -0.5 → -1.0
- -0.5 → -1.0
- > -0.5 → 0.0

To avoid problems caused by floating-point arithmetic use the `decimal` data type which is precise in terms of the decimal numeral system.

To develop a 'custom' rounding to the nearest greater or the nearest lower number you can use [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx) or [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx) respectively. They are both available for `double` and `decimal` types.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.ceil()
```

Rounds up :) Hope that helps

And as stated.. 1.7345 should round down.. because 1.7351 will round up with Math.Round().
So, you have to know what you want..

```
Math.round() //Rounds
Math.floor() //Rounds down
Math.ceil() //Rounds up
```

Comment: Math.Ceil() does not feature handling of decimal digits. You will get an "integer" value from it.

Comment: No, Math.Ceiling can handle double and decimal types.. Also stated in Ondrej Tucny's answer.. and he is correct :)

Comment: `decimal` is a way to store numbers (with decimal digits). It has nothing to do with the way Math.Ceil() / Math.Floor() etc. behave. Have a look at the examples given in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c.aspx

What Ondrej is saying is, that you can use `Math.Floor / Math.Ceil` functions to create(!) your own custom rounding algorithm. That will involve some more arithmetic though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why `Math.Round()` works that way have been addressed by others.

Another way to get your desired result is to add 0.005 to the value:

`Math.Round(1.7346 + 0.005, 2, AwayFromZero)`